# Evaluating the limit (inequation)

Tags: real-analysis

Could you help me out how to calculate the limit $$\lim\limits_{j \rightarrow 0}{\frac{f(j(x_1-x_0)+x_0)-f(x_0)} {j(x_1-x_0)}\cdot(x_1-x_0) \leq f(x_1)-f(x_0)}\;, j\in[0,1]$$ Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "what happens to this inequation [I assume you mean inequality] when building the limit?" Also, what have you tried in order to solve the problem?

Comment: Are you missing a $j$ somewhere in the numerator? You currently have a constant term $f(x_0) \cdot (x_1 - x_0)$.

Comment: What is j, a function?

Comment: My bad, j $ \in [0,1]$

Comment: The question makes even less sense now...you have an inequality yet you want to calculate the limit of the LHS? Do you mean you want to prove the inequality? And again, what have you tried so far? (For all we know you may be 90% to the answer!)

Comment: Sorry, I was obviously too blind to see that what I wanted to know was lying right in front of me. Posted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

By definition $$f'=\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0}{\frac{f(h+x_0)-f(x_0)} {h}}\; $$ when $h=(x-x_0).$ We see that as j approaches 0 $$\lim\limits_{j \rightarrow 0}{\frac{f(j(x_1-x_0)+x_0)-f(x_0)} {j(x_1-x_0)}}=f'(x_0),$$ so when passing to the limit in the inequality  $$\lim\limits_{j \rightarrow 0}{\frac{f(j(x_1-x_0)+x_0)-f(x_0)} {j(x_1-x_0)}\cdot(x_1-x_0) \leq f(x_1)-f(x_0)}\;$$ we conclude that $$f'(x_0)\cdot(x_1-x_0) \leq f(x_1)-f(x_0).$$

Comment: "We conclude that the limit A less than or equal to B equals C less than or equal to B". What is this supposed to mean?

Comment: Well, after ${j \rightarrow 0}$ you see that  $f'(x_0)\cdot(x_1-x_0) \leq f(x_1)-f(x_0).$

Comment: OK. A more readable version would be: "Passing to the limit in the inequality $\lim\limits_{j \rightarrow 0}{\frac{f(j(x_1-x_0)+x_0)-f(x_0)} {j(x_1-x_0)}\cdot(x_1-x_0) \leq f(x_1)-f(x_0)}$, we conclude that $f'(x_0)\cdot(x_1-x_0) \leq f(x_1)-f(x_0)$."

Comment: Okay, do you agree with my edits now?

Comment: Well, the answer is readable now. I suppose you were given the inequality $${\frac{f(j(x_1-x_0)+x_0)-f(x_0)} {j(x_1-x_0)}\cdot(x_1-x_0) \leq f(x_1)-f(x_0)}$$ somewhere? You did not state it in the question above. In fact, your question asked the readers to prove a certain inequality for $f$ without giving them any information about $f$.

Comment: I was told that f is a convex function, which shows $f((1-j)x_0+j\cdot x_1) \leq (1-j) \cdot f(x_0)+j\cdot f(x_1) $ if $ j\in [0,1]$, what leads to the upper inequality. I probably should've mentioned that. I will keep it in mind for my next post though.